# Play 2.1 sbt-jasmine-plugin getting not found: value jasmineSettings error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, jasmine

I am trying to integrate jasmine tests with play builds.

I found the sbt-jasmine-plugin from the guardian (https://github.com/barnesjd/sbt-jasmine-plugin) in this blog post (http://perevillega.com/post/2013/01/26/26/executing-jasmine-tests-in-play-204/)

I followed the steps, with some (I believe) minor modifications because of the version used in the blog post.

For instance I have this in my project/project/Plugins.scala file

```
object Plugins extends Build {
    lazy val plugins = Project("plugins", file("."))
    //.dependsOn(uri("git://github.com/guardian/sbt-jasmine-plugin.git#1.1"))
    .dependsOn(uri("git://github.com/guardian/sbt-jasmine-plugin.git#0.7"))
}
```

I've tried both versions of the plugin the latest from github and the one used in the post.

As for my projects/Build.scala file I have this

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
seq(jasmineSettings : _*)
//.settings(jasmineSettings : _*)  //this adds jasmine settings from the sbt-jasmine plugin
.settings(
  // Add your own project settings here
  // jasmine configuration, overridden as we don't follow the default project structure sbt-jasmine expects
  appJsDir <+= baseDirectory / "app/assets/javascripts",
  appJsLibDir <+= baseDirectory / "public/javascripts/vendor",
  jasmineTestDir <+= baseDirectory / "test/assets/",
  jasmineConfFile <+= baseDirectory / "test/assets/test.dependencies.js",

  // link jasmine to the standard 'sbt test' action. Now when running 'test' jasmine tests will be run, and if they pass
  // then other Play tests will be executed.
  (test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn (jasmine)
)
```

I've tried both seq(jasmineSettings : _*) as used in github and .settings(jasmineSettings : _*) as used in the post.

Both ways always get me this error:

```
project/Build.scala:18: not found: value jasmineSettings
```

I run this with

```
play test
```

I've even tried to update dependencies, the first time I ran play test (on each version of the plugin) I saw stuff being downloaded, but the error is always the same.

The error seems to be common

https://github.com/guardian/sbt-jasmine-plugin/issues/2

Any advice? thanks!

Comment: Do you see any errors in regards to the plugin not being found?

Comment: Not really, the first time I ran play test it showed something was being downloaded. Then the error is always the same: not found: value jasmineSettings.

Any step I might be missing? do the things I have look good?

Comment: Are you able to share the project via github, etc?

Comment: No, I can not. Can you send private messages here?

Comment: By design, no. :)  But my email is on my profile.  I recently accepted ownership of the plugin, so I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Build.scala` file needs to import the plugin's name space, which the blog post you referenced fails to mention:

```
import com.gu.SbtJasminePlugin._
```